# I encrypted files and folders on my USB drive and now I can't open them anymore

Tags: windows, usb, encryption

I used Windows encryption to encrypt files and I exported the `.pfx` file to that exact same drive, so I had to use a password to open files every time and it was all fine until one day when I reinstalled my Windows and now the "certificate" that previously was on my Windows was now deleted by the re-installation. Yet I still know the password and still have the `.pfx` file that should allow me to decrypt the files, I think, but have no clue how to open it.

The files were encrypted on windows 10 and now I have windows 11. Tried using `openSSL` to extract the key but no tutorials work so I'm kind of stuck. Also I'm unable to move any of the files out of the USB stick nor make a copy to desktop.

Is this a lost cause or there's some way to recover it?

Comment: Without the certificate which you stored your only backup of the certificate on the very drive that was encrypted, your files are gone forever. OpenSSL cannot be used and inapplicable for a folder encrypted with Encrypted File System a feature of Windows 10 and Windows 11 Professional. The reason the files were accessible on the original installation is because you had already imported the certificate into the certificate store. Since you reinstalled Windows that certificate does not exist in the certificate store and your only backup of the certificate is permanently encrypted.

Comment: There was a safe way to do what you did, explicitly not encrypt the certificate contained in the folder, encrypted by the very certificate you’re using to encrypt the folder. Since you didn’t do that, the files are encrypted, and cannot be decrypted without importing the certificate in question

Comment: Yeah dumb move by me, anyway thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 3):

*If* you have an old disk with Windows 10,

- Make a disk image of the current state of the Win 11 PC.
- Restore the *old* Win 10 image.
- *Decrypt* and export files to another drive.
- Restore the Win 11 image.
- Import the decrypted files.